# SQL query can't execute when it contains selected autoincrement row

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have in one java class a method which `SELECT` one column from a table from my database, and that column is an `INT` type in the database, and then I selected items from that column, put in a `List<Long>` and method returns this `List`. Here is the method:

```
public List<Long> vratiSveSifreRacuna() throws SQLException {
    String sqlVratiSifruRacuna = "SELECT RacunID FROM racun";

    Statement stat = konekcija.createStatement();
    ResultSet  rs  = stat.executeQuery(sqlVratiSifruRacuna);

    Long racunID = 0L;
    List<Long> sifre = new ArrayList<>();

    while (rs.next()){
        //racunID = rs.getLong("RacunID");
        sifre.add(new Long(rs.getInt("RacunID")));
    }
    return sifre;
}
```

The problem is, when I start debuging line by line, on this line:

```
ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(sqlVratiSifruRacuna);
```

it crashes, it jumps on exception. It cannot execute this query and I don't know why, because similar queries it execute well. Do you know what could be the problem? Is the problem maybe because the column I want to select is autoincrement and primary key? I don't know...

Comment: Whats the error are you getting? how big is the table?

Comment: Also wrap the code inside vratiSveSifreRacuna in a try catch block and log the exception you are getting, this way you know what's the issue and how to handle it.

Comment: nullPointerException is the error. I red about this error but as I understand it should alert this error if my query is empty...But it is not, or at liest I don`t understand why is empty if it is...

Comment: It is very small table, 16 items only. I`m learning, not work.

Comment: Where you create/open the connection to db ... I guess `konekcija` ?

Comment: I make connection konekcija in some part of code which I didn`t represent.                                                                                                   private Connection konekcija;

    public void napraviKonekcijuMySql() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/Februar2016";
        String user="root";
        String pass="";
        konekcija=DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
    }

Comment: But connection is ok, I already worked with that database in the same class and it was ok.

Comment: But if you have an error in `ResultSet  rs  = stat.executeQuery(sqlVratiSifruRacuna);` there are only two lines before of that. So either `sqlVratiSifruRacuna` or `stat` are null.

Comment: Is it possible that the problem is because as I said already the column is autoincrement?

Comment: I dont think so, but you can try creating a new table on your db without autoincrement.

Answer (score 1):

Your public (assuming *static*) method needs the connection object passed into it as an argument as it is not available in the local scope:

```
public static List<Long> vratiSveSifreRacuna(Connection konekcija) throws SQLException {

    String sqlVratiSifruRacuna = "SELECT RacunID FROM racun";

    Statement stat = konekcija.createStatement();
    ResultSet  rs  = stat.executeQuery(sqlVratiSifruRacuna);
```

Otherwise include connection inside local context:

```
public static List<Long> vratiSveSifreRacuna(String url, String username, String password) throws SQLException {

    Connection konekcija = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

    String sqlVratiSifruRacuna = "SELECT RacunID FROM racun";

    Statement stat = konekcija.createStatement();
    ResultSet  rs  = stat.executeQuery(sqlVratiSifruRacuna);
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem finally so I wanted to share the solution. The problem was actually stupid, I accidentally put the code line which makes connection with database below the line where I called this method. So there where the method was called, sql query was actually empty, so it alerts error nullPointerException.